# Is it equally correct to state of square root of i is plus or minus -1 to the power 1/4?

Tags: complex-numbers

I understand that the two square roots of $i$ are

> $$\pm {1 \over \sqrt{2}} (1+i)$$

But when asked what is the square root of $i$, is it equally correct to give the answer as

> $$\pm {(-1) ^ {1/4}}$$

? And actually, since $\sqrt 2$ is defined to be only the positive root, so square root of $i$ can be just

> $${(-1) ^ {1/4}}$$

?

Comment: Do you mean the exponent on $i$ to be $1/2?$.  The fourth roots and the square roots of $i$ are all different.

Comment: sorry, I actually meant $$\pm {(-1) ^ {1/4}}$$ ... I was think of the root of root of $-1$ but wrote it as the root of the root of $i$

Comment: $i^{1/2}$ has two values.  But $(-1)^{1/4}$ has four values.

Comment: @GEdgar even with the rule like $\sqrt 2$ is only the positive root?

Answer (score 0):

This is easiest to see in polar form.  $i$ is at an angle of $\frac \pi 2$.  Its square roots are at angles of $\frac \pi 4$ and $\frac {5\pi}4$.  Its fourth roots are at $\frac \pi 8 + k\frac \pi 2$, which do not match at all.

Comment: sorry, I actually meant $$\pm {(-1) ^ {1/4}}$$ ... I was think of the root of root of $-1$ but wrote it as the root of the root of $i$

Answer (score 0):

I'll ignore $0$ throughout.  Also, $n$ will be a positive integer.

First, with the more familiar real numbers.  When $n$ is even, positive numbers have two distinct $n$th roots and negative numbers have none.  When $n$ is odd, all numbers have one $n$th root.

It is quite different for the complex numbers.  All non-zero numbers have $n$ distinct $n$th roots.

So, what you say cannot be correct as there will be two square roots but four fourth roots.

A further common problem is talking of **the** square root, etc.  Among the reals, we can choose that the positive square is the principal one and gets to be called **the** square root.  For the complex numbers, we cannot pick a preferred root so neatly and some familiar behaviour, e.g. $\sqrt{x}\times \sqrt{y} = \sqrt{xy}$ might not be true.